# print_function imported inside exec does not affect code afterwards

Tags: python, exec

(Python 2.7) Normally when I `exec` a python statement, the global dict is in the updated state after the execution. For example, in the following code, the `numpy` will be in globals after the execution, and I can continue using it. However, the `print_function` behaves differently. The membership test against `locals` and `globals` both fails, but I can see it and use it, and the print still behaves as the python 2 print statement. This is not necessarily something I want to avoid, but I would like to understand more about this. Why is it so?

```
exec("""
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy

# prints "haha hoho"
print("haha", "hoho")
""")

# Executes without an error.
print(numpy.zeros((2, 2)))

# Prints "('haha', 'hoho')". (why?)
print("haha", "hoho")

# No error. (why?)
print 'haha'

# Both print False.
print(print_function in globals())
print(print_function in locals())

# However, this prints without an error.
print(print_function)
```

UPDATE:

I made a mistake that the membership tests should use the names:

```
# Now both print True
print("print_function" in globals())
print("print_function" in locals())
```

And the future imports turns out to be a special future statement, which causes the compiling (when executing the `exec` statement) to generate different code. Therefore it only affects the execution of the code that are compiled by the corresponding `exec` statement.

UPDATE:

It turns out that in an interactive interpreter, such as the cells of a notebook, the effect of the future statement extends beyond the cell boundaries. However, if there is an `exec` statement in a cell, the future statement inside the `exec` still affects only the code to be `exec`'ed.